# Reordering a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,0,1,3,4,0,1,3}
```

This list must have a sequence of numbers from 0 to 4 repeatedly but it lacks of some numbers. How can I put the lacking numbers and hold the order of the sequences?

Comment: What do you know, and what don't you know, about the list in the general case? If you know that you want a list repeating 0,1,2,3,4 over an over again for n times, why don't you just create this list instead of taking an incomplete list where you need to fill in the missing numbers...?

Comment: Along with what @a20 is asking: more context is needed here

Comment: `Module[{r = Range @@ MinMax[list]}, 
 Flatten@Table[r, Ceiling[Length[list]/Length[r]]]]`

Comment: what happens after the ending 3? does the list stop or do we have to add 4?

Answer (score 5):

Given

```
seq = Range[0, 4]
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3}
```

and

```
fill[seq_, list_] := Flatten[seq & /@ Split[list, Less]]
```

then

```
fill[seq, list]
(* {0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4} *)
```

and also

```
fill[seq, {1,1,1,3,1,1}]
(* {0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ls = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3};
Table[Splice@Range[0, 4], Max[Last /@ Tally[ls]]]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

or using [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html)

```
ls = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3};
If[ls[[-1]] =!= 4, ls = Join[ls, {4}]]; 
SequenceReplace[ls, {n0 : 0 | 1 | 2 | 3, n1_} /;n1 != n0 + 1 :> Sequence[n0, n0 + 1, n1]]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

Answer (score 1):

Consider building your own list of whichever length you want instead:

```
listLength = 12;
PadRight[{}, listLength, Range[0, 4]]

(* Out: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3}
fun[{a_, b_}] := If[a > b, {a, b}, If[Range[a, b] == {a, b}, {a, b}, Range[a, b]]]
fun[#] & /@ Partition[lst, 2] // Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst//Table[Sequence@@Range[0,4],Length@Split[#,Less]]&


{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: In v12.1, `lst//Table[Splice@Range[0,4],Length@Split[#,Less]]&`

Answer (score 1):

```
SequenceReplace[#, {x__} /; (Less@x) :> Sequence @@ Range[0, Max@#]] & @ list
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Is this possibly what you mean?

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3};
Flatten@Join[list, 
  Complement[Range @@ MinMax@list, #] & /@ Split[list, Less]]

(*{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4}*)
```

This seems to satisfy:

> How can I put the lacking numbers and hold the order of the sequences?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3};
```

Create a [ReplicateLayer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplicateLayer.html) (new in 11.1) with `SequenceCount`

```
c = SequenceCount[list, x_ /; Less @@ x]
```

3

```
rl = Flatten @* Round @* ReplicateLayer[c];

rl @ Range[0, 4]
```

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
rl @ Range[1, 4]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

More generally

```
rl @ Apply[Range] @ MinMax @ list
```

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}